# Undefined Reference To 'cv::initModule_nonfree()' In Android

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, linker, android

I want to create an Android app which uses BOW + SVM in native (using C++) for predicting. Unfortunately I have problem with building the native part. Since the non-free module is not included in the OpenCV SDK for Android, I need to build the module myself, using [this tutorial](http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android). It seems I built the .so file successfully. Here is the output:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libopencv_java.so <= /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libnonfree.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libnonfree.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnonfree.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libopencv_java.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
```

So the problem comes here, when I have to add this .so file to my project. I added libnonfree.so to my jni folder. Then I edited the Android.mk. Here I provide my .mk files.

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES   := on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES  := on

include /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := nonfree_prebuilt #if I add this, it says undefined reference for everything in the cv namespace.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := SVMDetector.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE     := svm_detector

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        += /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS            := -Werror -O3 -ffast-math 
LOCAL_LDLIBS            += -llog -ldl 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

APP_PLATFORM := android-15
```

But this doesn't work. When I try to build the app, I get the following error:

```
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/svm_detector/SVMDetector.o: in function Java_org_elsys_thesisdiploma_cammect_FrameProcess_SVMDetect:jni/SVMDetector.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to 'cv::initModule_nonfree()'
```

When I click right button on `initModule_nonfree();`, Eclipse opens the nonfree.hpp file and here are it's contents:

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_NONFREE_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_NONFREE_HPP__

#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"

namespace cv
{

CV_EXPORTS_W bool initModule_nonfree();

}

#endif
```

But I'm not sure the linker knows where is the implementation of this method. Since it gives an error, it doesn't.

**EDIT**

If I add `LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true`, the project compiles successfully but it causes run time error:

```
 02-17 00:15:58.197: E/AndroidRuntime(8793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 00:15:58.197: E/AndroidRuntime(8793): Process: com.example.cammect, PID: 8793
02-17 00:15:58.197: E/AndroidRuntime(8793): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN2cv18initModule_nonfreeEv" referenced by "libsvm_detector.so"...
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you able to compile the demo program (`test_sift.cpp`) with the `Android.mk` attached in the zip file?

Comment: I haven't try yet. I'll try and write again. Do you think everything is fine with my mk scriptrs?

Comment: No, I don't because the linker will unable to resolve nonfree's symbols in the absence of `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: But as I said in the question, if I add the line with LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES "it says undefined reference for everything in the cv namespace."

Comment: I ran the demo project from here http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/opencv_nonfree_android_jni_demo with success. Still I don't know how to fix my application..

Comment: Do you have any ideas what to do?

Comment: find my answer below

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## My development environment is set up as follows:

- android-ndk-r10d (install path: `D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\android-ndk-r10d\`)
- OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk (install path: `D:\CODE\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\`), [Download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.10/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk.zip/download)
- OpenCV-2.4.10 (install path: `D:\CODE\OpenCV-2.4.10\`), [Download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.10/opencv-2.4.10.exe/download)

### Building the nonfree module

1. We actually only need to copy a few files from `OpenCV-2.4.10` source code to `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk`, namely:
   Copy the [nonfree](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/tree/master/_copy_to_opencv_sdk) folder from `OpenCV-2.4.10\sources\modules\nonfree\include\opencv2\` to `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2`.
2. Create a folder to hold our new project for `libnonfree.so`. Here, I call it `libnonfree`. Create a `jni` folder under `libnonfree`. Copy the following files from `OpenCV-2.4.10\sources\modules\nonfree\src` to `libnonfree\jni\` folder:

   - [nonfree_init.cpp](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree/jni/nonfree_init.cpp)
   - [precomp.hpp](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree/jni/precomp.hpp)
   - [sift.cpp](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree/jni/sift.cpp) (*use the original file*)
   - [surf.cpp](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree/jni/surf.cpp) (*use the original file*)
3. Building `libnonfree.so`:
   Create `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` scripts. This `Android.mk` is used to build `libnonfree.so`.

   - [Application.mk](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree/jni/Application.mk)
   - [Android.mk](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree/jni/Android.mk) (you should modify `OPENCV_PATH` where your `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk` is)

   `cd` into the project folder `libnonfree` and type `ndk-build` to build the `libnonfree.so`.

So far, you have got `libnonfree.so` along with `libopencv_java.so` and `libgnustl_shared.so` in `libnonfree\libs\armeabi-v7a` folder.
You can easily build any SIFT or SURF applications using those libraries. If you want to use SIFT and SURF in JAVA code in your Android application, you only need to write JNI interfaces for the functions you want to use.

### Building a sample application

1. Create a project folder call `libnonfree_demo`. Create a `jni` folder inside the project folder. Then copy `libnonfree.so` along with `libopencv_java.so` and `libgnustl_shared.so` into `jni`.
2. Create a [nonfree_jni.cpp](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree_demo/jni/nonfree_jni.cpp) in `jni`. It is simple SIFT test program. It basically reads an image and detects the keypoints, then extracts feature descriptors, finally draws the keypoints to an output image.
3. Create `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` inside `jni`:

   - [Application.mk](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree_demo/jni/Application.mk)
   - [Android.mk](https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree/blob/master/libnonfree_demo/jni/Android.mk) (you should modify `OPENCV_PATH` where your `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk` is)

   `cd` into the project folder `libnonfree_demo` and type `ndk-build` to build the `libnonfree_demo.so`.

At this point you can easily extend the sample app with your `SVMDetector`. Just copy the source and include files int to the folder `libnonfree_demo\jni` and add cpp files to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` in `Android.mk`.

The whole source can be downloaded from: https://github.com/bkornel/opencv_android_nonfree.

Original source from: http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android

Comment: @Kornel, this is a great summary. And a good update on the newer OpenCV package. I haven't updated that article for a while (sorry, too lazy). I will attach this link to the article, so that people who needs newer information can benefit from your great answer.

Comment: @kornel 

I followed thos step but it doesn't work. I get the following error 
In file included from jni/nonfree_init.cpp:43:0:
jni/precomp.hpp:46:22: fatal error: cvconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cvconfig.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/nonfree/nonfree_init.o] Error 1

Comment: You should put the line `#include "cvconfig.h"` into comment in precomp.hpp.

Comment: If you're looking for pre-compiled libnonfree.so files. This github repo has : https://github.com/beartung/nonfree-opencv-android

Comment: @Kornel How can I get the nonfree libs in OpenCV 3.1 for Android?

Comment: @Kornel LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file error in ndk-build. can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874357/android-ndk-build-error-local-src-files-points-to-a-missing-file   question

Comment: @Kornel I'm having some trouble following your tutorial, could you help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212588/using-opencv-nonfree-module-in-android Thanks

Comment: Is there an updated version of this process for 2.4.13.3?  Anything older has the `libpng` vulnerability and can't be uploaded to the playstore.

Comment: Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079701/using-android-studios-c-support-to-build-nonfree-opencv-modules ?

Answer (score 3):

May I add that, in order to use the new libraries in the running application, there are the following steps to do:

1) in your folder libnonfree/libs/[TARGET PLATFORM]/, there are now 3 files:
- libgnustl_shared.so
- libnonfree.so
- libopencv_java.so

in your own project (my IDE is the Android Studio), you have a folder src/main/, with the subfolders:
- java
- res

create a new folder (if not already there): "jniLibs" [this folder is auto-parsed by Gradle]

COPY the 3 above-mentioned folders under "libnonfree/libs/" into the "jniLibs" folder. you end up with a structure like that:
[screenshot of the jniLibs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJaxi.png)

/app/src/main/jniLibs/[armeabi, armeabi-v7a, ...]/[libgnustl_shared.so, libopencv_java.so, libnonfree.so]

2) Somewhere in your code, you have a line like this:

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_10, this, mLoaderCallback);
```

this line tells your app to dynamically load the pre-compiled library from the locally-installed OpenCV Manager. In order to use the self-compiled non-free version, we replace the above line with the following:

```
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        System.loadLibrary("nonfree");
    }
```

now, we made sure to use the nonfree-included libraries we provide with the app.

3) well, run a SURF descriptor:

```
Bitmap mPhotograph = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_image_path);
Mat real_image = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(mPhotograph, real_image);
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_real = new MatOfKeyPoint();
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
detector.detect(real_image, keypoints_real);
```

while before, the app would return with a bad signal, this time it does its job and you can evaluate the resulting keypoints.

Comment: If you want pre-compiled .so files. Here they are : https://github.com/beartung/nonfree-opencv-android/tree/master/libs

Comment: This answer + the prebuilt "libnonfree.so" and "libopencv_java.so" files worked wonders for me. (I didn't have to add "libgnustl_shared.so" for some reason)