# Opencv SIFT undefined references issue

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In function `keypoint_calc(cv::Mat)':
FilePath/MyFirstOpenCVJNI-master/jni/first-opencvjni.cpp:35: undefined reference to`cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(int, int, double, double, double)'

./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/first-opencvjni/first-opencvjni.o: In function `sift_descriptor(cv::Mat, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >)':
FilePath/MyFirstOpenCVJNI-master/jni/first-opencvjni.cpp:45: undefined reference to`cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(int, int, double, double, double)'

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <opencv2/flann/flann.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define  LOG_TAG    "cpp-file"
```

are my includes.

And on those mentioned lines i have following code.

```
cv::Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT> feature_detector = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(200);
```

and

```
cv::Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT> feature_detector = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(200);
```

I'm a noob to JNI any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Undefined reference* is reported by the **linker**. Your project (**Android.mk** or **CMakeLists.txt**) should include the OpenCV libraries. SIFT is patented, therefore it is not part of the free prebuilt OpenCV Android distribution. You can either build **libnonfree.so** separately and use it as a prebuilt shared library in your app, or compile SIFT as a static library.

Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510045/undefined-reference-to-cvinitmodule-nonfree-in-android), but they may require adaptation for the latest (3.2) version, and the new NDK release. If you don't care about the latest version, you can also download [prebuilt binaries](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android/sift_surf_opencv_android_package.zip?attredirects=0).